# How to use pdfbox to replace pictures in pdf files

Tags: pdfbox

I found a code:

```
        PDResources res = page.findResources();
    Map<String, PDXObjectImage> imgs = res.getImages();
    res.setXObjects(newImgs);
    page.setResources(res);
    PDDocument newDcoument = new PDDocument();
    newDcoument.addPage(page);
    newDcoument.save(pdfname);
```

But the code is invalid,Is there any other way

Comment: Please link to PDF and the new image. There is no general solution because we don't know the name of the image resource. And run ExtractImages and compare the old image with the new one (same size?)

Comment: thanks，same size，just the color change，Are there any relevant examples?

Comment: I think there are two steps, the first step is to delete the original picture of the pdf, and the second step is to add the picture after changing the color in the original position, but I did not find a relevant method

Comment: Deleting makes it more complex. The core of the solution would be to use `PDResources.put(name, xobject)` on the page resource (if it is there!) but for that you need to know the name and have created the new image with one of the `PDImageXObject` static methods. If you share the PDF one could tell the name and how to access it, by looking at the PDF with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Beware, if the existing image is inlined, the situation is much different. Also it could be in an Xobject or a pattern, even in a type 3 font character...

Comment: thanks,The pdfbox version ： 2.0.20，my pdf(http://www.filedropper.com/signed).  I added two images (different colors) under FRM. According to different requirements, I only need to switch to display one of the images.

Comment: That is an electronically signed file. Changing it would invalidate the signature.

Comment: It indeed is signed. But without any degree of DocMDP. Thus, it is possible to change annotations. If images in annotations would suffice, therefore, there are options.

Comment: Yes, you can invalidate the signature，Finally, I chose `RandomAccessFile` to find the signature and then replace the keyword.

Comment: Ah, so you already have solved the issue for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose `RandomAccessFile` to find the signature and then replace the keyword.